# XML editing -- &#x09; not rendering

Tags: xml

I have not worked much with XML before but I need to edit a line of text which displays in a text box. For some reason, I am able to use the return code -- 

But in the same line, the tab or the space code does not work --

Ideas, thoughts, what else might I want to look at. Below is the line of code from my xml file.

```xml
<VisualTemplateParameterData ObjectName="ReceptionPointPage" 
                             ObjectId="456" 
                             LanguageCode="en" 
                             ParameterName="Text1" 
                             ParameterValue="Is this &#xA;your first name,&#xA;first initial?:&#x09;#FirstfirstName&#xA;&#xA;Is this your last name, first initial?: &#x09;&#09;#FirstlastName&#xA;&#xA;Is this your case number?: &#x09;#CaseNumber"/>
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: `&#x09;` is definitely a tab character. It if's not showing up as a tab character in whatever is displaying the text, then that probably has something to do with whatever is consuming your XML. What is `VisualTemplateParameterData` and in what way are you using it? I did a Google search for it, but the only result I got was this question.

Comment: Please clarify "does not work". What do you expect?